# How to put FlowFiles from NiFi to an Ignite Cache

Tags: apache-nifi, ignite

I am new to both NiFi and Ignite. I am trying to stream FlowFiles to Ignite using the PutIgniteCache processor. However, I get the error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. I have the default config for PutIgniteCache and using Filename as the Ignite Cache Entry Identifier.

I honestly think I'm missing some simple configuration of either NiFi or Ignite, has anyone encountered this error before?

**EDIT:** Below is my bootstrap.conf file for NiFi, with added arguments (17-23) for Ignite to work on Java 9.

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Java command to use when running NiFi
java=java

# Username to use when running NiFi. This value will be ignored on Windows.
run.as=

# Configure where NiFi's lib and conf directories live
lib.dir=./lib
conf.dir=./conf

# How long to wait after telling NiFi to shutdown before explicitly killing the Process
graceful.shutdown.seconds=20

# Disable JSR 199 so that we can use JSP's without running a JDK
java.arg.1=-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true

# JVM memory settings
java.arg.2=-Xms512m
java.arg.3=-Xmx512m

# Enable Remote Debugging
#java.arg.debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000

java.arg.4=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

# allowRestrictedHeaders is required for Cluster/Node communications to work properly
java.arg.5=-Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true
java.arg.6=-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol

# The G1GC is still considered experimental but has proven to be very advantageous in providing great
# performance without significant "stop-the-world" delays.
java.arg.13=-XX:+UseG1GC

#Set headless mode by default
java.arg.14=-Djava.awt.headless=true

# Master key in hexadecimal format for encrypted sensitive configuration values
nifi.bootstrap.sensitive.key=

# Sets the provider of SecureRandom to /dev/urandom to prevent blocking on VMs
java.arg.15=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom

# Requires JAAS to use only the provided JAAS configuration to authenticate a Subject, without using any "fallback" methods (such as prompting for username/password)
# Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html, section "EXCEPTIONS TO THE MODEL"
java.arg.16=-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true

# Added arguments to make Ignite work with Java 9
java.arg.17=--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED 
java.arg.18=--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED 
java.arg.19=--add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED 
java.arg.20=--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
java.arg.21=--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED
java.arg.22=--illegal-access=permit
java.arg.23=-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2

###
# Notification Services for notifying interested parties when NiFi is stopped, started, dies
###

# XML File that contains the definitions of the notification services
notification.services.file=./conf/bootstrap-notification-services.xml

# In the case that we are unable to send a notification for an event, how many times should we retry?
notification.max.attempts=5

# Comma-separated list of identifiers that are present in the notification.services.file; which services should be used to notify when NiFi is started?
#nifi.start.notification.services=email-notification

# Comma-separated list of identifiers that are present in the notification.services.file; which services should be used to notify when NiFi is stopped?
#nifi.stop.notification.services=email-notification

# Comma-separated list of identifiers that are present in the notification.services.file; which services should be used to notify when NiFi dies?
#nifi.dead.notification.services=email-notification
```

**nifi-app.log**

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:906)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:307)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.ignite.AbstractIgniteProcessor.initializeIgnite(AbstractIgniteProcessor.java:111)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.ignite.cache.AbstractIgniteCacheProcessor.initializeIgniteCache(AbstractIgniteCacheProcessor.java:108)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.ignite.cache.PutIgniteCache.initializeIgniteDataStreamer(PutIgniteCache.java:210)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:52)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.lambda$initiateStart$4(StandardProcessorNode.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1536)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:897)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1736)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1589)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1042)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:964)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:850)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:749)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:499)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:479)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:304)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, reconCnt=10, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:677)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1531)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Thread has been interrupted.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.spiStart(ClientImpl.java:260)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1832)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:255)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl.spiStart(ClientImpl.java:252)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

**nifi-bootstrap.log**

```
2019-02-28 10:05:33,264 INFO [main] o.a.n.b.NotificationServiceManager Successfully loaded the following 0 services: []
2019-02-28 10:05:33,266 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STARTED
2019-02-28 10:05:33,266 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_STOPPED
2019-02-28 10:05:33,266 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Registered no Notification Services for Notification Type NIFI_DIED
2019-02-28 10:05:33,283 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2019-02-28 10:05:33,283 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: /home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0
2019-02-28 10:05:33,284 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java -classpath /home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./conf:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/nifi-framework-api-1.9.0.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/nifi-nar-utils-1.9.0.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/nifi-api-1.9.0.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/nifi-properties-1.9.0.jar:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./lib/nifi-runtime-1.9.0.jar -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 --illegal-access=permit --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m --add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED  -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED  --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED  -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -XX:+UseG1GC -Dnifi.properties.file.path=/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./conf/nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=33547 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/logs --add-modules=java.xml.bind org.apache.nifi.NiFi 
2019-02-28 10:05:33,308 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 5184
2019-02-28 10:05:33,390 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: Unknown module: ALL-UNNAMED  specified to --add-exports
2019-02-28 10:05:33,392 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: Unknown module: ALL-UNNAMED  specified to --add-exports
2019-02-28 10:05:33,392 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: Unknown module: ALL-UNNAMED  specified to --add-exports
2019-02-28 10:05:33,898 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Bootstrap requests on port 41749
2019-02-28 10:05:43,319 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
2019-02-28 10:05:43,319 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader (file:/home/rasmus/Desktop/nifi-1.9.0/./work/nar/extensions/nifi-hive-nar-1.9.0.nar-unpacked/NAR-INF/bundled-dependencies/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
2019-02-28 10:05:43,319 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader
2019-02-28 10:05:43,319 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
2019-02-28 10:05:43,319 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: What Java version are you on?

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace of the error from the nifi-app.log?

Comment: @alamar I am using JDK 9

Comment: @mattyb I didn't know that file existed, so I looked in it and found Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ignite requires Java 7 or above. Current Java version is not supported: 9. Though it says on Ignite's site that Java  9 is supported but you need to pass a few parameters to the JVM. I'm guessing that is for the JVM that NiFi is running?

Comment: @RasmusKarlbäck correct, you can pass parameters to NiFi's jvm using the file `bootstrap.conf`. Just add `java.arg.N={your_parameter}`

Comment: @BenYaakobi I have added the parameters specified on https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started#section-running-ignite-with-java-9-10-11 but still get the same error. I wrote the arguments as: java.arg.17=--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED etc. Should I write them in another way?

Comment: No, this is the right way(assuming that `java.arg.17` is not taken).
Did you write all of the parameters(in different "java.arg.N" of course)? Better just send your `bootstrap.conf`

Comment: @BenYaakobi I edited the original post with the bootsrap.conf file, since it was too large to post in a comment.

Comment: Could you provide your `nifi-bootstrap.log` as well?

Comment: Can you please show full error stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the post now with `nifi-bootstrap.log` and the error from `nifi-app.log`

Comment: Take look to my Custom process, it may help you https://github.com/wahid18benz/Apache-NiFi-Custom-Processor

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are running some very old version of Apache Ignite which definitely will not work under Java 9. You should upgrade to latest Apache Ignite 2.7 (and keep those options for Java 9).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to do currently... NiFi's [ignite dependency](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-ignite-bundle/nifi-ignite-processors/pom.xml) is an old one that does not support Java 9. You can try to recompile it yourself with the new version or downgrade your Java version and in the meantime, [create an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI/summary) regarding this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I downgraded to Java 8, I also tried with Java 7 but my current version of NiFi doesn't support Java 7. I am getting a new error, as can be seen in the updated `nifi-app.log`. From what I can see, the current version of Ignite that I have is 2.7.0 and NiFi only supports Ignite 1.6.0, is this correct?

Comment: So in other words, installing Ignite 1.6.0 would in theory solve my problem?

Comment: @RasmusKarlbäck very likely

Comment: So, did you try this?

Comment: I tried it, the error disappears but the other errors remain the same. I have updated the `nifi-app.log` with the errors.

Comment: Could you have any malformed configuration?

Comment: I got an answer from a person associated with NiFi and apparently this is a bug and there is nothing to be done at this time. Also version 1.6.0 of Ignite is irrelevant to our project, so we will be looking for another solution.